# Rename "Related Tags" to indicate the special search behavior

Tags: feature-request, tag-search

When you search for a tag, a list of "Related Tags" shows up. Clicking on a related tag will add it to the query and search for original and the related tag.

This is a nice feature, but right now, it pretty much can only be discovered by accident. None of the other tags on the page (i.e. the interesting/ignored tags directly underneath it, and the tags on the search results) show this behaviour.

Right now, there is absolutely no indication at all in the UI that clicking on a tag from the "related" list is any different from clicking on a tag from the identically styled "Interesting Tags" list directly below (or am I missing something?).

So I propose to simply change **Related Tags** to something more telling like

- **Combine with...**
- **Show only results containing...**
- or something to that effect...

The alternative solution would be to extend the special behaviour to all tags on the page, but I don't think that this would be all that useful.